# Не удается получить атрибут value

Tags: javascript, c#, html, cefsharp

Есть **html** страница и от туда нужно получить значение атрибута `value` из `input`.
Для этого я использую **cefSharp** .

```
(function() { var sb = document.getElementById('sidebar');
                var query=document.getElementById('query');
                return query.getAttribute("value");
                })();
```

Без всего лишнего код выглядит так. Так вот `return` возвращает пустую строку, даже если я туда что либо впишу.
Получить атрибут `class` мне удалось

```
   <input type="text" name="query" id="query" placeholder="Поиск" 
   autofocus="autofocus" class="overflow">
```

Value скрыт как я понял. Так как получить его при помощи **webbrowser** мне удавалось. Вопрос как получить или задать атрибут `value`, или хотя бы подскажите как исправить.

Comment: просто `return query.value` не работает?

Comment: Тоже пробовал он мне `null` возвращает.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Все работает правильно. Давайте взглянем на ваш HTML код:

```
<input type="text" name="query" id="query" placeholder="Поиск" 
   autofocus="autofocus" class="overflow">
```

> [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) возвращает значение указанного атрибута элемента. Если
>   элемент не содержит данный атрибут, могут быть возвращены `null` или `""`
>   (пустая строка);

Так как `input` не содержит аттрибут `value` поэтому вы и получаете значение `null` или пустую строку. Также из документации:

> **Примечание:** 
>   Имеет смысл использовать [`hasAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/hasAttribute), чтобы проверять наличие
>   атрибутов перед вызовом [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute), если может быть такое, что
>   выбранный элемент не будет содержать искомого атрибута.

Я бы рекомендовал вам использовать `value` вместо `getAttribute`, покажу на примере, почему (добавим `value=""` в `input`):

```js
function getValue() {
  var query = document.getElementById('query');
  // пустая строка
  console.log(query.getAttribute("value"));
  // корректное значение
  console.log(query.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="query" id="query" placeholder="Поиск" autofocus="autofocus" class="overflow" value="">

<button onclick="getValue();">Get input value</button>
```

Разница в том, что `query.value` - это значение реального времени, и если пользователь изменит значение текстового поля, он будет содержать это и покажет новое значение. В то время как `query.getAttribute('value')` будет показывать исходное значение.

Ссылка на оригинал: [Difference between Element.value and Element.getAttribute(“value”)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11973716/5275890)

Comment: `query.value="Text"`; в return отправляет `null`, а если написать `query.setAttribute("value","Text");` он возвращает Text. Но значение на странице не меняется.(query - TextBox вписанное значение он тоже не видит.)

Comment: @Абдулла, если `value` не было и вы выполните `query.value="Text"` то `return` отправит `null` - это нормально. Когда вы делаете `setAttribute` - вы же добавляете аттрибут, поэтому после этого получаете значение. На странице ничего не меняется - это тоже нормально. Все описанное вами поведение - нормально :)

Comment: Такс не знаю как, но теперь `query.value="Text"` задается текст и возвращает **Text**. Но если я напишу что нибудь в самом TextBox он вернет мне написанное а не **Text**. Мне нужно задать значение и что бы оно сразу там отобразилось.

Comment: @Абдулла я не совсем понял о чем вы, но отвечу. Если у вас в HTML-разметке будет аттрибут `value="Text"`, то у вас сразу это значнеие отобразится в `input`, соответственно `placeholder` отобразится, когда вы из `input` все уберете. Про спецэфичность `value` и `getAttribute('value')` я вроде бы написал в ответе.

Comment: Я все это понял, но тогда почему `"query.value=\"" + addressText.Text + "\";\n" + ` возвращает мне значение addressText.Text, а отображается в textBox пустая строка.

Comment: `string fs = "(function() {\n" +
                "var b=document.getElementById('sidebar').
                getElementsByClassName('float');\n" +
                "var query=document.getElementById('query');\n" +
                "query.value=\"" + addressText.Text + "\";\n" +
                "for(var i=0;i<b.length;i++){\n" +
                "b[i].click();\n" +
                "}\n" +
                "return query.value+\" \"+b.length;\n" +
                "})();\n";`  
Код пишется в c#. Это весь скрипт который должен выполниться.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш скрипт работает корректно, измените значение `value` для тега `input` в html, чтобы скрипт возвращал не `null`

Comment: Я ошибся он возвращает не `null`, а пустую строку. А изменить его я могу только через браузер вписав значение, но увы это безрезультатно. Строка остается пустой.